# Don't execute flag in http response?

Tags: httpresponse

I was reading about attacks on sites with the ability to upload and download files. Some attacks were about uploading a jpg which is really a html file and a comment about what if you want users to be allowed to store html and download them (or perhaps view them in the browser w/o using the save as feature).

Is there some type of flag i can use to say do not execute? I will want users to view images or video files other have uploaded. What if i'd like user html to be displayed but i dont want to force users to download them (content-disposition attachment).

Is there a way i can say hey here is some user data. It could be an image so i should allow img src to work. It could be an html so i'd like users to see it but dont allow it to read/write cookies/localstorage/call ajax request/etc?

-edit- Come to think of it. All of my user data is hosted on its own cookieless subdomain for static files. That would get rid of many problems i mention but what else is left to deal with? Also i believe my mime response completely depends on what my web server does (nginx atm) which could simply be look at the file extension.

-edit2- I adjusted my nginx config to add the `application/unknown` Content-Type. It seems to do exactly what i want. I saw a suggestion to use octet-stream for unknown files but that causes browsers (at least firefox) to try to download it even if its a jpg capable being viewed in browser.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on the `Content-Type` in your HTTP Response.

Browsers handle the data returned by the `Content-Type` in HTTP response.

For example if let say a user uploads a HTML file in a upload field supposedly for photo upload, as long as your web server gives `Content-Type` as `image/jpeg` (or `image/png` et al) the browser should handle it as an image - and in this case an invalid image because the image contains weird HTML stuff inside instead of the usual binary.

In any case, if you are feeling unsecure, you can always peek into the file data during upload validation.

Comment: I let the server guess. If i have a file.jpg even if its a gif the server (nginx is my choice atm) does it stuff and calls it a jpg (i havent tested what happens if i use a gif). But i heard that browsers try to guess what type it is and ignore mimes. But i guess if they execute stuff its a browser problem not mine?

Comment: If you respond with the correct MIME type and the browser shows it as a HTML file instead then it'll be the browser problem. They're supposed to listen to `Content-Type` by standard.